# How get maximum value of DATALENGTH of all fields on current record

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm looking for how I get maximum value of DATALENGTH of all fields on current record. Ex:

```
| No | Fullname      | Age | Address                        | MaxLenField |
| 1  | Markus Michel | 21  | Avenue San Peter Lost number 8 | 30          |
| 2  | George Andrus | 35  | Avenue Colorado Freud number 4 | 32          |
```

The last field contain Maximun value of DATALENGTH of all fields on current record.

I got all fieldname of my temp table with:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = '##Temp35321456'
```

Any idea?

Thank's.

Comment: Here's a [blog entry](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/maximum-length-of-data-in/) which should answer your question...

Comment: Thank you Peter Schneider for blog entry!

Comment: Thank you Zohar Peled for correction in the question.